# SwiftUI Map Change Region Programmatically to Show Any Annotations Added

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mapkit

I'm trying to use the new Map in SwiftUI. I would like to change the visible region
programmatically to include all of the annotations that are added programmatically,
similar to the way you can show a bounding box for a route overlay in the older UIMap.
I have not found anything in the documentation to do this. I created my own approach
by getting the min/max values for the latitude and longitude of each annotation and
then creating a center for the new region and a span. Both of these involve some math.
My result works for my North America location, but I will need to add significant
complexity to handle the cases where the annotation area encompasses the equator, the
date line or the prime meridian. Before I do so, I'm hoping someone has a solution
that I have missed.

Here is my solution:

```
struct MyMapView: View {
    @StateObject var myMapVM = MyMapViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            let m = Map(coordinateRegion: $myMapVM.region, annotationItems: myMapVM.centers) { site in
            
                MapAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: site.lat, longitude: site.long)) {
                    GroupAnnotationPinView(title: site.name)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            openMapWithCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: site.lat, longitude: site.long), name: site.name)
                        }//on tap
                }//map annotation
            }//map
            m.onAppear {
                //this works, so reference to Map seems to work ok
                //print(m.body)
            }
        
            Button(action: {
                myMapVM.createCoordinateRegion()
            }, label: {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.pencil")
                    .resizable()
                    .frame(width: 44, height: 44)
                    .padding()
            })
                .padding(.bottom, 20)
        }//v
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }//body

    func openMapWithCoordinate(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, name: String) {
        let place = MKPlacemark(coordinate: coordinate)
        let mapItem = MKMapItem(placemark: place)
        mapItem.name = name
        mapItem.openInMaps(launchOptions: nil)
    }//open
}//my map view

struct GroupAnnotationPinView: View {
    @State private var showTitle = true
    let title: String
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Image(systemName: "mappin")
                .font(.title)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
        }//v
    }//body
}//group anno view
```

And the View Model

```
class MyMapViewModel: ObservableObject {

    @Published var annotations: [MKAnnotation] = []
    @Published var region = MKCoordinateRegion(
        center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.334_900,
                                       longitude: -122.009_020),
        latitudinalMeters: 10000,
        longitudinalMeters: 10000
    )

    let centers: [Center] = [
        .init(name: "One", lat: 37.334, long: -122.009),
        .init(name: "Two", lat: 37.380, long: -122.010),
        .init(name: "Three", lat: 37.400, long: -122.010),
        .init(name: "Four", lat: 40.000, long: -120.000)
            //.init(name: "Four", lat: 37.600, long: -121.800)
        ]

    func createCoordinateRegion() {
    
        //you need to fix this to account for dateline, prime meridian and equator in span
    
        let maxX = centers.max(\.lat)
        let maxY = centers.max(\.long)
        let minX = centers.min(\.lat)
        let minY = centers.min(\.long)
        //print("minX.lat is ", minX?.lat ?? "nil")
        //print("maxX.lat is ", maxX?.lat ?? "nil")
        //print("minY.long is ", minY?.long ?? "nil")
        //print("maxY.long is ", maxY?.long ?? "nil")
    
        guard let minXS = minX?.lat, let maxXS = maxX?.lat, let minYS = minY?.long, let maxYS = maxY?.long else { return }
        
        let deltaX = maxXS - minXS
        let deltaY = maxYS - minYS
    
        let newCenterLat = minXS + deltaX / 2
        let newCenterLong = maxYS - abs(deltaY / 2)
        //print(newCenterLat)
        //print(newCenterLong)
    
        let newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: newCenterLat, longitude: newCenterLong), span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: max(deltaX, deltaY), longitudeDelta: max(deltaX, deltaY)))
    
        region = newRegion

    }//create coord region


}//class

extension Sequence {
    func max<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T)  -> Element? {
        self.max(by: { predicate($0) < predicate($1) })
    }
    func min<T: Comparable>(_ predicate: (Element) -> T)  -> Element? {
        self.min(by: { predicate($0) < predicate($1) })
    }
}// ext seq

struct Center: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let lat: Double
    let long: Double
}//center
```

Any guidance would be appreciated: Xcode 13.2.1 iOS 15.2

Answer (score 2):

I do this by converting each annotation coordinate to an `MKMapRect`:

```
let rect = MKMapRect(origin: MKMapPoint(coordinate), size: MKMapSize(width: 0, height: 0))
```

`MKMapRect` is able to calculate a union and knows how to handle the 180th Meridian (see method `spans180thMeridian`:

```
private(set) var union: MKMapRect? = nil
func union(_ rect: MKMapRect) {
    guard let union = self.union else {
        self.union = rect
        return
    }
    self.union = union.union(rect)
}
```

After you're done, you can convert it into a region and use it:

```
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(union)
```

Be aware that this cuts the AnnotationViews at the edge in half, so you have to calculate some space around it.

**Alternative solution:**
This is one of MANY reasons to prefer the old `MKMapKit` where you just call

```
mapView.showAnnotations(specificAnnotations, animated: true)
```

This changes the region to show `specificAnnotations` while keeping the other annotations on the map and not cutting AnnotationViews in half.

Comment: Very interesting. I'll give it a try. If this works for me, the advantage would be the meridian spanning. That might be worth changing to this approach.